# Making a Function that Strictly Increases and Decreases Once between Roots

Tags: functions, roots

Given any continuous function with finite roots such that $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$, is there a way to modify it so that it strictly increases and decreases once between those roots? You may not necessarily know where the roots are, but you do have intervals for where the roots lie.

Here is a picture of the output of the modification to a function:
[image]

Comment: OK, next question then - what counts as a "modification"?

Comment: @CalvinKhor You can do things like, $\sqrt{f(x)}$, $g(f(x))$ where $g(x)$ is some function of yours, $\mathbb{sgn} (f(x))$, $f(\sqrt(x))$, etc. Just not changing $f$ itself.

Comment: If you think of curves instead of functions, then what you have to do is stretch out any extra folds inbetween the roots. One way to do this is to select a point on the curve between the roots and stretch the curve as far up as you can.

Comment: I'm all but convinced that this is "equivalent" to finding the roots

Comment: @Allawonder That sounds promising. How would you do that?

Comment: @WhoAmI Wish I knew.

Comment: If it is possible, it has to be some sort of "nonlocal" operation, in the sense that no function of the form $F(x) = G(f(x))$ can work. Also, its "equivalent" to finding roots in the sense that: if you could find the roots, the procedure of Allawonder is quite easy to describe, if annoying to write down an explicit computer algorithm ("pull up on the graph to make it taut"). Conversely, if you could create the function that strictly increases and decreases, as a side effect, you would have found the roots of $f$ as the minimum points of the new function...